Snowman cartoon
I hope someone can help me. I remember a cartoon show that was pretty cool where a snowman was made with the help of the moon. The cartoon had only snowmen, no people. They used to live in igloos. There was the main snowman and then there were other snowmen, like one was a pilot. There was also an amusement park.
I saw it on Saudi Channel 2. The cartoon was in English. 
It wasn't the Frost the snowman.

Please stop defacing your posts into rubbish!

The cartoon you're looking for is the French cartoon Bouli.




Yeah! You got it. Thanks a lot.
